# Upload png file to specific folder in Ubuntu server using php

Tags: php

How do I upload a png file to specific folder with php?
I've been trying to use this:

```
$target_file = "capes//" . basename($_POST["Username"] . ".png");
```

but when users upload a png file it uploads it to the root directory of the website and renames it to capes//(filename).png. I would really appreciate it if someone tells me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Oooof, is there write access on the root folder? That's bad.... You should configure an upload folder in your webserver and have write access only there and nowhere else.

Comment: you need to add more of your code, in addition what is `//` that is not a proper path.

Comment: Please improve this question.

Comment: `/` cannot be part of a filename, it's a directory separator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to move an uploaded file (Example: **Test.png**) to root/capes/**Test.png**?

You have not gave much infomation, but we could help you more if we seen more of your code

Note that linux is Case sensitive unlike windows. Please check the following and report back:

1) Make sure the **capes** folder is called **exactly** capes, and **not** Capes
2) Make sure the **capes** folder has the right **permissions** (Example: **777**)
3) Does this **code** work on other systems / servers? (**The problem could be the code**)

Comment: This code works on windows, but not on linux, The capes folder is exactly called capes, and giving it full permissions (777) seems to make the upload not work.